# Test for directory existence in C

Tags: c, testing, permissions, directory

I have a function that should create a directory.  I want to test to make sure that the directory is

- created, and
- has the correct permissions

I can't use `lstat` since I get `EPERM` when I do so (I assume I'm not supposed to know that much about a directory).  So what else should I use?  I can try to open it it with `opendir`, but that doesn't tell me what its permissions are.

Comment: stat is the right way to do it afaik. Something else is going on.

Comment: This isn't actually a C question, but rather a file system API question.  What OS are you working on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, yes you should use `stat` or `lstat`, depends whether the dir is a symbolic link or not.  If you are getting EPERM from `lstat`, that probably means that the dir you are passing to `lstat` is a link and it points to someplace where you do not have the apropriate permissions to even see if a dir or file exists.

In fact, are you sure you should be using `lstat` and not just `stat`?

Comment: arg.  I was being stupid.  Your confidence helped me find my screwup.  Thanks!